# How to use xml-apis in web application that will be running under JBoss 5.1?

Tags: java, jboss

We need to use jasper reports in web application under JBoss on AIX.

Today we get a problem when we tried to add `xml-apis` to `WEB-INF/lib` - JBoss did not start at all.

What should we do in order to use `xml-apis` under JBoss?

PS.
As far as I know we need org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator and org.w3c.dom.svg.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to? JBoss already has those APIs in its standard library set, your WAR should automatically have access to them. Try removing the JAR from your `WEB-INF/lib`.

The only way to replace JBoss's copy of that JAR is to place it in the top-level JBoss `lib/endorsed` directory, and make sure it doesn't clash. This will affect the entire JBoss server, though, so you need to very sure you know what you're doing. JBoss itself uses these libraries.

Comment: As far as I know we need org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator and org.w3c.dom.svg.*